# How do you indicate a past from the perspective of a future, when that past is in a "when"-clause?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

**Question**

Which of the following is grammatical (maybe more than one), and which colloquial?

> (a) I won't do it when you tell me not to.
>
> (b) I won't do it when you have told me not to.
>
> (c) I won't do it when you told me not to.

For context imagine that the speaker is a child who ran into trouble by ignoring his mother's previously given instructions.  He now says this would not happen again.

**Background**

I came to have this question while reading different versions of this passage from The Little Red Riding Hood.

> Rotkäppchen aber dachte: Du willst dein Lebtag nicht wieder allein vom Wege ab in den Wald laufen, wenn dir's die Mutter verboten hat.
>
> Le Petit Chaperon Rouge cependant pensait: "Je ne quitterai plus jamais mon chemin pour aller me promener dans la forêt, quand ma maman me l'aura interdit."
>
> And Little Red Riding Hood thought to herself: "As long as I live, I will never leave the path and run off into the woods by myself if mother tells me not to."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b) is probably most accurate.

a) is acceptable grammatically

c) is not right, as it backshifts too far—from future to past

That said, the most colloquial would be form a), but with "if":

- I won't .... if you tell me not to

There's a reason the English version uses "if" rather than "when":  Of course she won't run off in the woods WHEN her mother tells her not to—if she were going to, she would do it AFTER her mother tells her not to.

I can't speak for why the German and French versions say "wenn" and "quand" respectively, except to say that English grammar is not identical to German grammar nor to French grammar.

Comment: But it is perfectly idiomatic in English to say *Don't do it when I tell you not to* - meaning *whenever* and indeterminate in time. *Don't do it if I tell you not to* would suggest some actual forthcoming event. 'Can I climb the cliffs when we go to the seaside, Mummy?' 'Possibly, I don't know how high they are, but don't do it if I tell you not to.'.